# Boostrap modal form does not execute POST method on server

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc, forms, bootstrap-modal

I have a button that calls a modal form

```
 <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#agregarProducto">Agregar Material </a>
```

the modal is presented in this way

[image: Modal]

up there all right, I have to say that the above works when you are working locally (localhost), the modal form is this:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="agregarProducto">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">               
                <h5 class="modal-title">Agregar Material</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="alert alert-dismissible alert-info">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button>
                    <strong>Tener en cuenta!</strong> <a> para agregar más de una unidad habilite</a><strong> agregar cantidad.</strong>
                </div>
                <form id="myForm">
                    <label>Agregar Cantidad</label> &nbsp;&nbsp;
                    <input type="checkbox" id="idcheckcantidad" />
                       <input type="text" class="form-control" name="cantidad" id="idcantidad" disabled="disabled" />
                    <br />
                    <label>Codigo Producto</label> &nbsp;&nbsp;
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="codigoproducto"  id="idcodigoproducto" autofocus="" />
                    <br />  

                </form>
            </div>            
             <div class="modal-footer">
                <input type="button" value="Agregar Material" class="btn btn-primary" id="btnSubmit" />
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>                
             </div>
         </div>
    </div>
```

The javascript code that is executed when you submit to my modal is:

```
   <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#btnSubmit").click(function () {

                var myformdata = $("#myForm").serialize();

                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "/Despachos/AgregarProducto",
                    data: myformdata,
                    success: function () {                     
                        $("#agregarProducto").modal("hide");
                        window.location.href = '@Url.Action("Create", "Despachos")';
                    },
                    error: function (xhr, text, error) {
                    console.log(xhr.status + " => " + error);
                    }
                })
            })
        })
    </script>
```

this code calls a method in my controller called AddProduct:

```
   public JsonResult AgregarProducto(int codigoproducto, int? cantidad)
        {
            //CONSULTO LOS PRODUCTOS QUE EXISTEN EN EL DETALLE
            var despachotmp = db.DespachoDetalleTmps.Where(o => o.Email == User.Identity.Name && o.Kn_CodigoProducto == codigoproducto).FirstOrDefault();

            if (despachotmp == null)
            {
                //BUSCO EL PRODUCTO
                var producto = db.Productoes.Find(codigoproducto);

                if (producto == null)
                {
                    ViewBag.Error = "Debe Seleccionar un Material Válido";
                    return Json(false);
                }

                if (cantidad == null)
                {
                    despachotmp = new DespachoDetalleTmp
                    {
                        v_Nombre = producto.v_Nombre,
                        Kn_CodigoProducto = producto.Kn_CodigoProducto,
                        Email = User.Identity.Name,
                        d_Cantidad = 1,
                    };

                    db.DespachoDetalleTmps.Add(despachotmp);
                }

                if (cantidad != null)
                {
                    despachotmp = new DespachoDetalleTmp
                    {
                        v_Nombre = producto.v_Nombre,
                        Kn_CodigoProducto = producto.Kn_CodigoProducto,
                        Email = User.Identity.Name,
                        d_Cantidad = Convert.ToInt16(cantidad),
                    };
                    db.DespachoDetalleTmps.Add(despachotmp);                   
                }
            }

            else
            {
                if (cantidad == null)
                {
                    despachotmp.d_Cantidad += 1;
                    db.Entry(despachotmp).State = EntityState.Modified;                   
                }

                if (cantidad != null)
                {
                    despachotmp.d_Cantidad += Convert.ToInt16(cantidad);
                    db.Entry(despachotmp).State = EntityState.Modified;                   
                }
            }

            db.SaveChanges();

            var jsonResult = "Json Result";
            return Json(jsonResult);
        }
```

All the above works locally, but when I publish the solution on my web server, this form is displayed, but when I click on the submit it does not execute (it does not do anything!), It's the first time I work with boostrap manners, I am doing it right? what is happening that when publishing my solution on my server this form stops working?

any help for me?

Comment: This may be a event delegation issue. Do you know if the dialog is created by bootstrap on the fly or whether it is on the page during initial load and presented to the user when they select the button?...

Comment: `it does not execute (it does not do anything!)` - does anything get logged in the **browser** tools console?

Comment: there is no notification error in my console, both in the announced solution and in the local, you suggest? @JaromandaX

Comment: How can I know this? Can I find out with the inspector of my console? @War10ck

Comment: it's unusual that your browser does absolutely nothing in the console when you click on submit - so, not even the network activity triggered by form submit is shown?

Comment: Yes sir! when looking at the activity of my network, 404 error was found, cause xhr, html type, could you help me solve my problem?
@JaromandaX

Comment: yes I can ... see that 404 error? that means the request is to an URL that does not exist - please make sure the URL exists

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be an issue with the path in your URL, `"/Despachos/AgregarProducto"` in the server might not be the same directory as `"/Despachos/AgregarProducto"`. Try using `'@Url.Action("AgregarProducto", "Despachos")'` in your `ajax` url

```
 <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#btnSubmit").click(function () {

                var myformdata = $("#myForm").serialize();

                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: '@Url.Action("AgregarProducto", "Despachos")',
                    data: myformdata,
                    success: function () {                     
                        $("#agregarProducto").modal("hide");
                        window.location.href = '@Url.Action("Create", "Despachos")';
                    },
                    error: function (xhr, text, error) {
                    console.log(xhr.status + " => " + error);
                    }
                })
            })
        })
    </script>
```